# Is there any way to remove a program that has been installed with a .tar.gz file?

Tags: software-installation, packaging

Is there any way to remove a program and all of its executable files and docs that have installed from a .tar.gz file (for example on an Arch Linux)

by :

```
./configure
make
make install
```

**Answer :** I thought always there is a short way to uninstall all the programs that were installed from a source, no matter who wrote them (and how), but apparently, sometimes there is no way (except manually )and this may be the reason to build a package manager.

Comment: Your answer is too broad as a .tar.gz is an archive and can contain anything from source code to scripts to compled binaries. If you compiled a program from source via make it again is going to depend on the package and where you installed it to. Generally you would use `PREFIX=` to install to /usr/local or /opt . If you just installed it to your system you may overwrite system files installed and managed by yoru package manager, apt with ubuntu. If the package maintaner was kind there is a clean and/or uninstall in the make file. If not you would manually find and remove the files.

Comment: Yes, you right. I'm not a professional in Linux, and I thought always there is a short way to uninstall all the programs that were installed from a source, no matter who wrote them (and how), but apparently, sometimes there is no way (except manually )and this may be the reason to build a  package manager